# Javascript, HTML: Loop placeholder name with multiple values

Tags: javascript, html

How to make placeholders fade in and fade out. After 1 second the placeholder `"Search by ID"` will change to "Search by Name" after 1 second it will change to `"Search by Location"` then after 1 second go back to `"Search by ID"` and so on... (a loop).

```
<div id="search">
    <input id="inquire" type="text" placeholder="Search by ID" />
</div>

add:
placeholder="Search by Name"
placeholder="Search by Location"
```

Comment: That pretty basic js, what have you tried that you have a problem with?

Comment: I'm starting to learn basic JS and I need some support from the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can try like as -

```js
/*Define your texts in an array*/
var placeholders = ['Search by ID','Search by Name','Search by Location'];
var length  = placeholders.length;
var counter = 0;
/*Store the object to a variable*/
var inquire = document.getElementById('inquire');

function ChangePlaceholder(){
  /*Compare with placeholders length*/
  if(counter>=length){
    counter=0;
  }
 /*Update placeholder text*/
 inquire.setAttribute('placeholder',placeholders[counter]);
 /*Update counter as Index*/
 counter++;
}
/*Call ChangePlaceholder() function after 1 seconds, [1000 millisecond = 1 second]*/
setInterval(ChangePlaceholder,1000);
```

```html
<div id="search">
    <input id="inquire" type="text" placeholder="Search by ID" />
</div>
```

Here is the details about [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function

Comment: You could avoid the `length` and `counter` variables by doing `function ChangePlaceholder() {placeholders.push(placeholders.shift());  inquire.setAttribute('placeholder',placeholders[0]);}`.  But that may be confusing to a beginner.  (Good answer as-is, already upvoted.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using setInterval :

```
//select input
var input = document.getElementById('inquire');

//array of strings to loop through
var strArr = ['Search by ID', 'Search by Name', 'Search by Location'];
//counter to keep track of loops
var counter = 0;

//interval that will execute at one second intervals
var interval = setInterval(function() {

//sets the placeholder attribute to a different string 
input.setAttribute('placeholder',  strArr[counter])
  counter++;

  if (counter == 3) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}, 1000)



<div id="search">
  <input id="inquire" type="text" placeholder="Search by ID" />
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6erhs5r/12/

Comment: Why `counter == 3` condition? If there is more than 3 elements.

Comment: And why `jQuery` selector? He is talking about JavaScript only.

Comment: There are 3 placeholders he wants so the stopping condition is 3. It will iterate until it gets to 3. jQuery can be considered javascript. It's perfect for beginners as well.

Comment: He wanted as loop, Start from the beginning when completed. :( :(

Comment: I have changed it to pure javascript / and for it to iterate forever.

Comment: Thank you. :) Always try to select `document.getElementById('inquire')` outside of the loop/function, When not required. You are selecting every time in Inner Function, This is not ok for standard coding.

Comment: Yes I forgot that. I updated the answer. I did everything in a haste before.